# BigDecimal scaling issue in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Currently I have a Proportionate Value of 0.588235294 with that I need to multiply it and sum of total value must be 100. With Excel the calculation is working as perfect but in same when i tried with help of BigDecmial api there is a point variations.

The below screenshot is the output from **Excel**.

[image]

**In Java**

```
public class CalculateRates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigDecimal f1 = new BigDecimal(65);
        BigDecimal f2 = new BigDecimal(45);
        BigDecimal f3 = new BigDecimal(35);
        BigDecimal f4 = new BigDecimal(25);

        BigDecimal totalRate = f1.add(f2).add(f3).add(f4);

        System.out.println("Total Value : " + totalRate);

        BigDecimal proportionatedValue = new BigDecimal(100.00).divide(totalRate, 9, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);

        System.out.println("ProportionatedValue : "+proportionatedValue);

        BigDecimal f11 = f1.multiply(proportionatedValue).setScale(8);
        BigDecimal f12 = f2.multiply(proportionatedValue).setScale(8);
        BigDecimal f13 = f3.multiply(proportionatedValue).setScale(8);
        BigDecimal f14 = f4.multiply(proportionatedValue).setScale(8);


        System.out.println(f11 + ":: " + f12 + ":: " + f13 + ":: " + f14 );

        System.out.println("Total : "+f11.add(f12).add(f13).add(f14));

    }

}
```

The **output** of first and second value is different by one digit at the last

[image]

[image]

What causing this issue? and How we can approach it for a common solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN`, you should use `ROUND_UP` if you really want to have the values exactly as in the Excel sheet.

Comment: I guess `HALF_UP` is more like Excel

Comment: @Henry: Thanks for your comment, guess you're right. Let's wait for the OP's response, I'd edit my answer.

Comment: You guys can have a clear look on the above. There is  no problem in the  ProportionatedValue . The problem occurs on the object of f11 and f122 I have also used all the rounding option given from BigDecimal I unable to achieve the exact result given by Excel.

Comment: @Arun: but you are calling the multiply() function without specifying the approximation mode. You could try by specifying it in there too, not just in the divide().

Comment: I have tried with all the options but still couldn't